# Execute PostgreSQL statements upon deployment to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, github, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, codeship

I am working on an application that has source code stored in **GitHub**, build and test is done by **CodeShip**, and hosting is done in **Amazon Elastic Beanstalk**.

I'm at a point where seed data is needed on the development database (**PostgreSQL in Amazon RDS**) and it is changing regularly in development.

**I'd like to execute several SQL statements that are stored in GitHub when a deployment takes place.**  I haven't found a way to do this with the tools we're using, so I'm wondering if there are some alternatives.

Comment: what language do you use? there are specific tools that can be used per language

Comment: The project is JavaScript, but I'm open to anything that gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

If these are the same SQL statements, then you can simply create an .ebextension ([see documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html)) that will execute them after each deploy.
If the SQLs are dynamic per deploy, then I'd recommend a database migrations management tool. I'm familiar with rails that has that by default abut there's also a [standalone migrations tool](https://github.com/thuss/standalone-migrations) for non-rails projects. Google can suggest many other options.

Comment: Yeah, these are the same statements and are written to handle any existing data.

Comment: in that case, the solution is as written to use .ebextensions